# could we use "who" in the clause instead of "whom"

Tags: grammar

The original sentence is
"This leads to constant bickering between the brothers, neither of whom wants to be called unfilial."

Regardless of the meaning of the sentence, could we use "who" in the clause instead of "whom" if getting rid of "neither of"?

Comment: Note that you can't just remove *neither of* without changing the meaning of the sentence or having it become ungrammatical. You would also need to remove the comma and change *wants* to *do not want*. To make this clear, I would actually provide the changed version of the sentence rather than just describing it.

Answer (score 2):

As Jason Bassford said, you need to do a more significant rewrite to make it work. But, you can replace who with whom in the following sentence:

> This leads to constant bickering between the brothers, who do not want to be called unfilial.

If you don't know already, "whom" is used when "who" is the object or indirect object of a sentence and following a preposition. "Who" is used when dealing with the subject.

In the rewritten sentence, "who" has become the subject of the subordinate clause beginning "who do not want ...".